# PySide6 Disable Experimental Interaction with Qt Designer?

Tags: python, pyside6

When running my application, I keep getting the following error messages

```
qt.pysideplugin: Environment variable PYSIDE_DESIGNER_PLUGINS is not set, bailing out.
qt.pysideplugin: No instance of QPyDesignerCustomWidgetCollection was found.
qt.pysideplugin: No instance of QPyDesignerCustomWidgetCollection was found.
qt.pysideplugin: No instance of QPyDesignerCustomWidgetCollection was found.
qt.pysideplugin: No instance of QPyDesignerCustomWidgetCollection was found.
```

According to the following link
https://www.qt.io/blog/qt-for-python-6.1

as well as this post
["Environment variable PYSIDE_DESIGNER_PLUGINS is not set, bailing out."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68528717/environment-variable-pyside-designer-plugins-is-not-set-bailing-out)

This is due to some experimental feature regarding Qt Designer. We have no .ui files in our project nor are we using Qt Designer; is there some way to completely disable this feature? We do not want it.

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured it out. I guess at one point there were .ui files in our project. I found several calls to `QtRegisterWidget` which were causing the error messages seen above. i.e. we were trying to register UI files which didn't exist.

Removing the register statements fixed the problem and everything is working now. Hopefully this helps someone in the future; happy coding everyone.